# mongoose query return array instead of object

Tags: express, mongoose

I faced a strange problem with the mongoose query. when I do `db.collection.find()` it should be return a object as expected. And I got so in `mongo` shell

> [image: mongo_shell]

When I do a similar query in my express router endpoint I got array instead of an object. Like

```js
[
    {
        "dishes": [
            "5eca615117611c0480320c12",
            "5eca615117611c0480320c15"
        ],
        "_id": "5ecae7eb2e746b312cfdf59e",
        "user": "5ec644d06715633270d0414d",
         ...
    }
]
```

which causes error in my frontend react application. Here is my schema in favorite model:

```js
var favoriteSchema = new Schema(
  {
    dishes: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Dish',
        unique: true,
      },
    ],
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

And here is my express endpoint:

```js
.get((req, res, next) => {
    Favorites.find({})
      .then(
        (favorite) => {
          res.statusCode = 200;
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.json(favorite);
          console.log(favorite);
        },
        (err) => next(err)
      )
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  })
```

I heartily thank if anyone helps me to figure out this.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use `findOne` with mongoose, if you are looking for a single result or null. If you use `find` you expect more than one row as result.

Bare in mind you should handle the case where "favourite" is null (when you can't find the row you are looking for). At that point you might want to return a different response.

Answer (score 0):

.find({parameter}) returns all the objects from database by the given parameter.